# How Can I Make SAML SP with @node-saml/node-saml?

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, saml, microsoft-entra-id

I'm developing SAML SP.
And I use @node-saml/node-saml library.
Although I made the following source, SAML authentication dosen't work.
Could you tell me how to fix or good reference source of making SAML SP.

vc.ts

```
export const SAML = async () => {
  const express = require("express");
  const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
  const { SAML } = require("@node-saml/node-saml");

  const app = express();
  const port = 3001;

  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

  const spOptions = {
    issuer: "saml_XXX",
    cert: "MII...XXX",
    assert_endpoint: "https://5XXX",
    audience: "https://5XXX",
  };

  const sp = new SAML(spOptions);

  // SAMLrequest
  app.get("/login", (req: any, res: { redirect: (arg0: any) => void }) => {
    const request = sp.createLoginRequest();
    res.redirect(request);
  });

  // SAML Assertion
  app.post(
    "/assert",
    (
      req: { body: { SAMLResponse: any } },
      res: {
        status: (arg0: number) => {
          (): any;
          new (): any;
          send: { (arg0: any): any; new (): any };
        };
        redirect: (arg0: string) => any;
        send: (arg0: string) => void;
      }
    ) => {
      const response = req.body.SAMLResponse;
      sp.parseLoginResponse(
        response,
        (err: any, profile: any, loggedOut: any) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log("err:", err);
            return res.status(500).send(err);
          }

          console.log(profile);

          if (loggedOut) {
            return res.redirect("/");
          }

          res.send("Login successful!");
          return "OK!";
        }
      );
    }
  );

  return app;
};
```

saml-request.ts

```
import { error } from "console";
import { SAML } from "../../../lib/vc";

const createSamlRequest = async (req: any, res: any) => {
  const app = await SAML();
  app(req, res);
  try {
    console.log("success");
  } catch {
    console.log("failed", error);
  }
};

export default createSamlRequest;
```

sorry for my poor English and skill.
Thank you for your kindness.

I may have a spOptions contents...if you know please tell me how to set SAML application in Azure Entra ID .
(I have already read the below doc. but I coudnot make what is correct for Assertion Consumer Service URL and entity Id. Now I set the single application base url which works this source for Assertion Consumer Service URL.

doc
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-pages/security/authentication/saml2-settings-azure-ad)

Answer (score 0):

firstly in your vc.ts file, you are exporting a function that returns an Express app. i suggest to directly export the app instance instead of a function.

```html
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import { SAML } from "@node-saml/node-saml";

const app = express();
const port = 3001;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const spOptions = {
  issuer: "saml_XXX",
  cert: "MII...XXX",
  assert_endpoint: "https://5XXX",
  audience: "https://5XXX",
};

const sp = new SAML(spOptions);

// SAMLrequest
app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  const request = sp.createLoginRequest();
  res.redirect(request);
});

// SAML Assertion
app.post("/assert", (req, res) => {
  const response = req.body.SAMLResponse;
  sp.parseLoginResponse(
    response,
    (err, profile, loggedOut) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("err:", err);
        return res.status(500).send(err);
      }

      console.log(profile);

      if (loggedOut) {
        return res.redirect("/");
      }

      res.send("Login successful!");
    }
  );
});

export default app;
```

and in your saml-request.ts file, use the app instance instead of the exported function directly.

```html
import { error } from "console";
import app from "../../../lib/vc";

const createSamlRequest = async (req: any, res: any) => {
  app(req, res);
  try {
    console.log("success");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("failed", err);
  }
};

export default createSamlRequest;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, after redirect I got a CORS error. 
Althogh I add a Access-Control-Allow-Origin settings in next.config.js, the error does not disappear. Could you tell me how to resolve it?